# Произношение двойного Р

Tags: орфоэпия, удвоенные-буквы

Задумался, во всех ли словах двойное Р произносится коротко, как если бы была одна буква Р. И мне показалось, что во всех, кроме слов *"террор",* *"террариум"* и, возможно, производных от террора (*терроризм, террорист, террористка*). Почему-то даже хочется произнести в слове *"теракт",* пишущемся с одним Р, "рокочущее" Р.

Скажите, правильно я воспринимаю эти слова? И какие вообще соображения на этот счёт и ещё примеры можно придумать?

Comment: Возможно, в качестве примера еще подойдет слово коррида.

Comment: Точно, Стася, спасибо!)

Comment: Возможно, еще барракуда, ирреальный, баррель.

Comment: Да, "ирреальный" уж точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, ответа не знаю. Даже сам вопрос не очень понятен, ибо спорно, есть ли такое явление, что в одних словах двойное Р произносится не так, как в других. И не стал бы отвечать, наверное, но автор другого ответа подвиг.

Конечно же никакого здравого смысла, тем более "смыслоразличения" (???) тут нет и быть не может. Вообще, когда на них ссылаются, это уже симптом.

Что может быть, так это некоторое влияние иностранных языков (особенно испанского, где Р - что одинарное, что удвоенное произносится так, что даже русскому мало не покажется). По мере освоения русским стремление порычать становится все менее ощутимым. Вот единственное объяснение - в предположении, что сам факт имеет место.

Отдельно по словам типа "ирреальный", "иррациональный" и проч. Здесь есть объяснение того, что на морфемных швах даже иноязычные слова хочется произнести четко.

А вообще тут надо с логопедом посоветоваться. У меня есть некоторый врожденный дефект речи, мне с детства трудно произносить сочетания "жр" и "шр" - поэтому я произношу их более энергично, со стороны вполне может восприниматься как удвоение Р. Может и у Вас что-то подобное, "неудобные" слова стремишься выговаривать четко...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Точно, испанское двойное Р мне очень нравится.)